# Specifying a DataType for a propertyinside a nested class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making a MVC5 website, and created a Viewmodel to be able to access multiple models/classes in my View. The Viewmodel contains classes generated by EntityFramework. It looks like this:

```
public class PersoneelskaartVm
{

    public PERSONEEL Personeel { get; set; }
    public GEBRUIKERS Gebruikers { get; set; }
    public List<SYSGROEP> LidVanSysgroep { get; set; }
    public List<RELSGRPS> LidVanRelsgrps { get; set; }
    public PERSONEEL_UREN UrenPerJaar { get; set; }
    public PERSOON_OVERW OverwerkPerJaar { get; set; }
    public CBOALGEMEEN Status { get; set; }
    public List<RELAFDELING> LidVanRelafdeling { get; set; }
    public List<PERSOON_VAKGROEP> LidVanPersoonvakgroep { get; set; }
    public List<VAKGROEP> LidVanVakgroep { get; set; }
    public List<competentieEntiteit> LidVanPersoonCompetentie { get; set; }
    public List<competenties> LidVanCompetenties { get; set; }

    //Volle lijsten:
    public List<CBOALGEMEEN> AlleBurgStaten { get; set; }
    public List<OVERWERK> AlleOverwerk { get; set; }
    public List<ONREG_TOESLAG> AlleOrt { get; set; }
    public List<CBOALGEMEEN> AlleStatussen { get; set; }
    public List<CBOALGEMEEN> AlleContractvormen { get; set; }
    public List<FUNCTIE> AlleFuncties { get; set; }
}
```

Traditionally i used `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` for DateTimes where i only need the date. But how can i achieve this for a property in `Personeel`? In `Personeel` is a property called `gebd`, so i'd like to set an datatype for `Personeel.gebd`.

The same is for a property in `Personeel` called `CreditCard` where i always used `[Datatype(DataType.CreditCard)]`

However i cannot change the auto-generated EF classes.

//EDIT: Because i couldn't explain myself very well, ill try to explain myself somewhat better.

In example if i have this model for my Webpage:

```
public class ExampleViewModel{
    public PERSOON Person{get;set;}
}
```

and PERSOON is defined as this:

```
public class PERSOON{
    public DateTime gebd {get;set;}
}
```

And i can't change the PERSOON class.

The output in a textfield in html Will be: 04-05-1985 00:00:00 if i access ExampleViewModel.Person.gebd

If i add the DataType markup ( [DataType(DataType.Date)] ), the output would be: 04-05-1985. So without the time as suffix.

But because my Viewmodel has nested Models in it, how can i apply the DataType markup in that Viewmodel to manipulate a property that is in a in a class, inside the Viewmodel.

I hope that i explained better.

Comment: The `DataType` annotation uses the `DataType` enum - which is useful for giving scope to `input` fields in your HTML. Is this what you're trying to do? You would not be able to add your own `DataType` (plus, `Personeel.gebd` is a property, not a type) It's not clear what you're asking/trying to do. If I might suggest a look into custom attributes, and creating custom HTML helpers if this is (loosely) what you're trying to get at?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What is your expected end result ?

Comment: A view model should not contain properties which are data models.

Comment: I updated my question @Shyju.

Comment: It is not @StephenMuecke? I follow this example from a tutorial on the Microsoft site

Comment: I cannot imagine any tutorial suggesting you do that for editing data (and if it is, ignore it). Your model should contain properties for the date and credit card and anything else your editing (and apply the attributes to those properties) or contain properties which are other view models

Comment: @StephenMuecke, sorry not Microsoft but CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC.

If you see in the 4th chapter, using multiple models in a Viewmodel, he does it like this way as well.

Comment: It might be acceptable for a display only view, but its not for a view where your editing data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @StephenMuecke. It is in fact an edit view. What is your take on this? What would be the most efficient and correct way to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117709/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-maarten-heebink).

Comment: Create a view model (a simple poco) **with properties only needed for that specific view** and use it

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine/override the auto generated model

```
public class ExampleModelMetadata
{
    [Display(Name = "Birthday")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Birthday {get;set;}
}

[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(ExampleModelMetadata))]
public partial class ExampleModel
{
}
```

This will then be applied even after you refresh your models from database.

Comment: I edited my question, as this is probably not sufficient for me i think.